# Divide the number of cell between two prototypes

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

as I am beginner I have a problem that may not be so pro to ask. 
I have two prototype collection view cell in my app, let's call them `Cell1` and `Cell2`, they both are in a same section.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as? customCell {
        return cell
    } else if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as? customCell {
        return cell
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

My problems starts from here:
in `numberOfItemsInSection`, I want to say for example draw 3 cell from prototype `Cell1` and 5 cell from `Cell2`.
I don't know how I divide the number of cell between two prototypes, could anyone help me on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have several options for this. If you know how many cells you will be having, lets say 8 you can just do a simple switch.

```
switch indexPath.item {
    case 0,1,2,3:
         let cell = .....
         return cell
     case 4,5,6,7:
         let cell2 = ....
          return cell
     default:
          let cell = ...
          return cell
}
```

you can also do a modulo approach, which will give you cell1 for even item numbers and cell2 for uneven. 
Without knowing your intentions directly, I can give you only a broad answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
       numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return 8
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if (0...2).contains(indexPath.item) { 
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as! customCell {
        return cell 
    } else { 
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as? customCell {
        return cell
    }

}
```